# My function doesn't return the expected output

Tags: javascript, function, sum, output

I wrote a fuction that must return if the sum of the first half of the digits is equal to the sum of the second half. What's wrong with my code?
thanks for helping me.

```
function isLucky(n) {
var digits = (n).toString(10).split("").map(Number)
var k = digits.length; 
var a = 0;
var b = 0;
for(let x = 0; x<k/2; x++){
    a+=n[x];
}
for(let x = k/2; x<k; x++){
    b+=n[x];
}
return (a===b); 
}
```

Comment: Try replacing `n` with `digits` in your `loops`

Comment: _"What's wrong with my code?"_ - It's not a [mcve] with input and the expected and actual output.

Answer (score 0):

You can't access digits of a number like an array. First convert it to a String and then use spread syntax to convert it to an array of digits.

```
function isLucky(n) {
    var digits = [...(n).toString(10)]
    var k = digits.length; 
    var a = 0;
    var b = 0;
    for(let x = 0; x<k/2; x++){
        a += +digits[x];
    }
    for(let x = Math.floor(k/2); x<k; x++){
        b += +digits[x];
    }
    return (a===b); 
}
```

Comment: OP already knows this: `var digits = (n).toString(10).split("").map(Number)` - but then uses the wrong variable (`n` instead of `digits`) -> typo -> vote to close

Answer (score 0):

Here is little code that does the comparison of the sums of digits of the 1st and 2nd halves of a number:

Try it. It will print the 2 halves and the result of the comparisons.

You can convert the code into a simple function.

```js
let MyNumber = 1234.5678;                     // the Number
MyNumber = (""+MyNumber).split(".");          // Split the number
let first_half=0, Second_half=0, a;           // Some vars
a=[...MyNumber[0]].map(e => first_half+=+e);  // Sum the first half
a=[...MyNumber[1]].map(e => Second_half+=+e)  // Sum the 2nd half

console.log(first_half, Second_half)          // Print 1st and 2nd halves

console.log(first_half == Second_half)       // Test if equal
```